# Itext Paragraph alignment issue in Android

Tags: java, android, pdf-generation, itext

I am creating PDF outfile file using itext library in android but Paragraph is not centered align while similar code is Java desktop application creates output with center align.

**I have also checked by using Element.ALIGN_CENTER and Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER but no success in android.**

**Android Code**

Here is my code in android for creating centered align Paragraph.

```
 Paragraph prefaceX = new Paragraph();
 prefaceX.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
 addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
 prefaceX.add(new Paragraph(getString(R.string.report_title), catFont));
 prefaceX.add(new Paragraph(getString(R.string.disclaimer), smallBoldMM));
 document.add(prefaceX);
```

where addEmptyLine is as follow

```
private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
    }
}
```

Output PDF in android
[image]

**Java Desktop application code**

```
Paragraph prefaceX = new Paragraph();
prefaceX.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
prefaceX.add(new Paragraph("Dummy Text", catFont));
prefaceX.add(new Paragraph("* Dummy Details ", smallBoldMM));
document.add(prefaceX);
```

Output PDF in Java Desktop

[image]

Font (catFont and smallBoldMM) are custom font and both are same as follow

```
private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18,
Font.BOLD);
private static Font smallBoldMM = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 7,
        Font.ITALIC)
```

**Please don't suggest to use tables.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the difference between your Android application and your Desktop application is the version of iText that is used.

You can get the same behavior by using `Paragraph` the way one would expect when talking about a paragraph.

```
Paragraph prefaceX = new Paragraph();
prefaceX.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
document.add(prefaceX);
document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
document.add(new Paragraph(getString(R.string.report_title), catFont));
document.add(new Paragraph(getString(R.string.disclaimer), smallBoldMM));
```

There is no reason why you'd want to put all the different `Paragraph` objects into one big `Paragraph`.

If you take a look at iText 7 (but you're using iText 5 or earlier), you'll notice that we make a distinction between the `Paragraph`object (single paragraphs) and the `Div` object (that can contain several `Paragraph` and other objects).

Comment: Hi Bruno Lowagie, Thanks for your help but I was using same iText version (5.5.4) in both android and desktop application. 
**I have created separate application for android and desktop application and it solved my problem.**
For some reason, I can't update code to use latest itext so I am using table to center align.